# Can Endofunctors be seen as the definition of equivalence classes? How is this useful?

Tags: category-theory

Functions can be seen as identifying equivalence classes on a set.  For instance, take a set $X$ and an endo-function $f: X \rightarrow X$.  Suppose the pre-image of $x_0 \in X$ is a set $A \subset X$, label this preimage with $x_0$.  Take this for all elements $x \in X$.  Then we have a definition of equivalence classes labelled by elements of $X$.  This applies to every function.

Next, consider an endofunctor, $F$, on a category $C$.  We take the view of an endofunctor as mapping arrows to arrows.  Every arrow has a pre-image and this pre-image is a a set of arrows.  Thus, the endofunctor $F$ defines a set of equivalence classes over the arrows of $C$ and they are themselves labelled by arrows of $C$.

Is this a standard interpretation?  Does it have a use?

Comment: But you're just talking about a special case of the first idea, when $f$ happens to be the morphism part of a functor, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Yes, I think so.  This view, of functions or functors, is it a general tool?  Does it have a use?

Comment: @KevinCarlson  Yes, I see them as being the same thing.  The use in Category Theory would be different though, if there is some.

Comment: What you describe does not produce a partition because there are elements of $X$ whose preimage is empty. You could require $f$ to be surjective (or I guess you could just filter out the empty sets which would be equivalent to considering $f$ as a [surjective] function onto its image) or you could define an equivalence relation via $x_1\sim x_2 \iff f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ and then calculate equivalence classes in the usual way. Also, there's no reason $f$ needs to be an endofunction, and there's not a lot of point in "labeling" the equivalence classes. The labels won't be representatives, for example.